# Formatting how a time and date display from a variable

Tags: php

My Variables are in my sql table stored as a date and time respectively.

for the date, when i display the variable it displays as 2014-06-09

```
<?php
echo $info['seasonbegin'];
?>
```

when i try and format it, no matter which variable i declare (beginning or end) it displays as Wednesday December 31st

```
<?php
echo date("l F jS", $info['seasonbegin']);
?>
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. For a time I am trying to do with similar code, it does the same thing, no matter the value of the variable it displays 6pm...

Thanks for any help

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument for [**date()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is a timestamp, so you need to convert your original date to a timestamp. You can do this with [**strtotime()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
echo date("l F jS", strtotime($info['seasonbegin']));
```